# Using For to add numbers as string in combobox text increasing by 0.1

Tags: delphi, combobox

I want to code adding numbers from 1 to 5 to combobox as text increasing by 0.1 in delphi 2010, but keep getting errors. I am a self-taught amateur coder and have never attempted this before.  This is what I tried:

```
procedure TfrmWines.FillCombos;
var
  c : TStringList;
  i : Double;
begin
  c :=  TStringlist.Create;
  with c do
  begin
    sorted  :=  True;
    duplicates  := dupIgnore;
  end;
  try
    wdatamod.wines.first;
    wdatamod.wines.DisableControls;
    while not wdatamod.wines.eof do
    begin
      c.Add(wdatamod.wines.FieldByName('country').AsString);
      wdatamod.wines.Next;
    end;
  finally
     edCountryLst.Items :=  c;
     wdatamod.wines.EnableControls;
     c.Free;
  end;
  edRating.Items.Clear;
  for i := 1 to 5 do
  begin
    edRating.Items.add(FloatToStr(0.1 +i));
  end;
end;
```

What am I doing wrong?  Any help with helping me figure out would be appreciated.  Combobox strings should 1, 1.1, 1.2, and so on up to 5.0.

Comment: Are the errors secret? Or why don't you tell us what they are?

Comment: @ Tom Brunberg.  Errror is "For loop control variable must have ordinal type"  I have tried extended and real as variable types

Comment: Indeed, you cannot use a `double` as a for loop variable.

Comment: As I thought. Maybe change variable `i` to integer.

Comment: @ Tom Brunberg.  Changed to Interval, but no string are added to the combobox.  No errors compiling, but nothing added to combox items.

Comment: I moved from OnCreate to OnActivate but only giving 1.1, 2.1, 3.1, 4.1, 5.1.

Comment: If `edRating` is the combobox you are looking at, it sure should have 5 items in the dropdown (you need to adjust your code to add lines up to 5.0).

Comment: Now, stop for a moment and think!

Comment: Thanks, but I am not sure what to do next. I need to inc 1 to 1.9, then 2-2.9, and so on.  I am not a professional coder.  I tried 1 to 4.9 but I get the first error all over again.

Comment: Is this question for real? You want to count from 10 to 50 and present a value that is count divided by 10. Do that please.

Comment: So I changed the    for 1 := 1 to 5    to    for i := 10 to 50    Now where to divided by 10?

Comment: @KBoykin `for i := 10 to 50 do begin edRating.Items.Add(FloatToStr(Double(i) / 10)); end;`

Comment: @Remy Lebeau  That gives Invalid typecast error.

Comment: @KBoykin: `for i := 10 to 50 do begin edRating.Items.Add(FloatToStr(i / 10.0)); end;`

Comment: @Remy Lebeau.  Thank you, thank you!.   That worked exactly as planned!   I was trying too hard and this is a much d simpler solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Remy Lebeau, this is the solution.

```
procedure TfrmWines.FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
var
  i : integer;
begin
  edRating.Items.Clear;
  for i := 10 to 50 do
  begin
    edRating.Items.add(FloatToStr(i /10));
  end;
end;
```

Again,  thanks!!!